How to Add a New Marker by Tapping on a Map in SwiftUI iOS 17?
I am trying to achieve a similar functionality to Google Maps.
When my user clicks on an existing marker, a sheet pops up showing them a page with the details of the marker.
However, if they click on the map (preferrably a long click) they should be able to add a new marker, and a sheet will pop up allowing them to enter the details of the new marker.
Here is what I have so far. I am close, but using onTapGesture is not ideal because it makes it difficult to tap on existing markers.
Also, it does not display the 'AddNewMarkerView' when I try adding a new marker.
I have a custom object called 'Custom Marker'
struct CustomMarker: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var category: String
    var notes: String


    // Implementing the hashValue property
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(location.latitude)
        hasher.combine(location.longitude)
        hasher.combine(category)
        hasher.combine(notes)
    }

    // Implementing the == operator for Equatable conformance
    static func ==(lhs: CustomMarker, rhs: CustomMarker) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
            lhs.title == rhs.title &&
            lhs.location.latitude == rhs.location.latitude &&
            lhs.location.longitude == rhs.location.longitude &&
            lhs.category == rhs.category &&
            lhs.notes == rhs.notes
    }
}

Then I have an array of markers as such:
@State private var markers: [CustomMarker] = [CustomMarker(id: "1", title: "First Marker", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.6764, longitude: 139.6500), category: "My Category", notes: "My Notes")]

I have an enum that checks which view to show in the sheet. 'details' if they click on an existing marker, and 'newMarker' if they clicked on a new location on the map and want to add a new marker.
enum ViewState {
    case details
    case newMarker
}

@State private var viewState: ViewState = .details

and I store the selectedMarker in this variable:
@State private var selectedMarker: CustomMarker?

and my sheet variable as such:
@State private var showingSheet: Bool = false

Finally, here is what I have in my content view to display my map and my sheet.
MapReader { proxy in
        
        Map(selection: self.selectedMarker) {
            
            // SHOW USER LOCATION
            UserAnnotation()
            
            // DISPLAY ALL USER'S MARKERS
            ForEach(self.markers) { marker in
                if self.viewState == .newMarker {
                    
                    Marker(marker.title, coordinate: marker.location)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    Marker(marker.title, coordinate: marker.location)
                        .tag(marker)
                        
                }
            }
            
        }
        .onTapGesture { position in
            
            self.viewState = .newMarker
            
            if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {
                
                let newMarker = CustomMarker(
                    id: "",
                    title: "",
                    location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude),
                    category: "",
                    notes: ""
                )
                self.markers.append(newMarker)
                self.selectedMarker = newMarker
                
            }
        }

        
        
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingSheet, onDismiss: {
        self.markers.removeLast()
    }, content: {
        switch self.viewState {
            
        case .details:
            MarkerDetailsView()
            
        case .newMarker:
            AddNewMarkerView()
                
        }
    })
    .onChange(of: self.selectedMarker, { oldValue, newValue in
        if newValue != nil {
            self.viewState = .details
            self.showingSheet = true
        } else {
            self.showingSheet = false
        }
    })

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much in advance :)

One of the issue you have is that CustomMarker need to have a unique id
for the code to work, in particualr the ForEach(markers).
So to Add a New Marker by Tapping on a Map in SwiftUI iOS 17, try this approach using a built-in id.
// to make it Hashable
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Hashable {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(latitude)
        hasher.combine(longitude)
    }
}

struct CustomMarker: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    var title: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var category: String
    var notes: String
}

enum ViewState {
    case details
    case newMarker
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var viewState: ViewState = .details
    @State private var selectedMarker: CustomMarker?
    @State private var showingSheet: Bool = false
    
    @State private var markers: [CustomMarker] = [CustomMarker(title: "First Marker", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.6764, longitude: 139.6500), category: "My Category", notes: "My Notes")]

    var body: some View {
        MapReader { proxy in
            Map(selection: $selectedMarker) {  // <--- here $
                // SHOW USER LOCATION
                UserAnnotation()
                // DISPLAY ALL USER'S MARKERS
                ForEach(markers) { marker in
                    Marker(marker.title, coordinate: marker.location) // <--- here
                        .tag(marker)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture { position in
                viewState = .newMarker
                if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {
                    let newMarker = CustomMarker( // <--- here, id generated for you
                        title: "",
                        location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude),
                        category: "",
                        notes: ""
                    )
                    markers.append(newMarker)
                    selectedMarker = newMarker
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet, onDismiss: {
         //  markers.removeLast()  // <--- here ???
        }, content: {
            switch viewState {
                case .details: MarkerDetailsView()
                case .newMarker: AddNewMarkerView()
            }
        })
        .onChange(of: selectedMarker, { oldValue, newValue in
            if newValue != nil {
                viewState = .details
                showingSheet = true
            } else {
              //  showingSheet = false  // <--- here ???
            }
        })
    }
    
}

// for testing
struct MarkerDetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("MarkerDetailsView")
    }
}

struct AddNewMarkerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("AddNewMarkerView")
    }
}
        

Note, there is no need to use self. anymore.
EDIT-1
try this example code to create a new Marker or show the details of an existing one.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var viewState: ViewState = .details
    @State private var selectedMarker: CustomMarker?
    @State private var showingSheet: Bool = false
    
    @State private var markers: [CustomMarker] = [CustomMarker(title: "First Marker", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.6764, longitude: 139.6500), category: "My Category", notes: "My Notes")]

    var body: some View {
        MapReader { proxy in
            Map(selection: $selectedMarker) {  // <--- here $
                // SHOW USER LOCATION
                UserAnnotation()
                // DISPLAY ALL USER'S MARKERS
                ForEach(markers) { marker in
                    Marker(marker.title, coordinate: marker.location) // <--- here
                        .tag(marker)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture { position in
                if let selection = selectedMarker, markers.contains(selection) {
                    viewState = .details
                } else {
                    viewState = .newMarker
                    if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {
                        let newMarker = CustomMarker( // <--- here, id generated for you
                            title: "",
                            location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude),
                            category: "",
                            notes: ""
                        )
                        markers.append(newMarker)
                    }
                }
                showingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            switch viewState {
                case .details: MarkerDetailsView()
                case .newMarker: AddNewMarkerView()
            }
        }
    }
    
}


Hello, thank you for your response, I added the unique ID like you have but it still hasn't solve the problem of being able to click on existing markers. Whenever I trying to click on an existing marker, it creates a new one right next to it.

updated my answer. You will need to adjust the code for your purpose, eg passing the  selectedMarker  to appropriate view.

Unfortunately, I am still unable to click on an existing marker. It just creates a new marker on top of it. I believe it's because of the onTapGesture. To click on an existing marker that tap would have to be very precise.

Consider putting an "add mode" toggle button on the map safe area. With add mode engaged, you can add a marker, otherwise the tap gesture will default to selection. You could also consider using a long press gesture for adding.

Adding a Button to select adding a Marker is the way to go. While in adding mode,
you need to adjust the Map MapInteractionModes.
Have a look at my github test code for how it works MapPoly
